# hibernate, join table and join column with complex addiction

Tags: spring, hibernate, join, mapping, joincolumn

While studying Hibernate I encountered this problem.
Making a query from the Contract tables (i want to get list avalible contracts in db).
I can't display Tariff entity fields in my jsp (e.g. Contract.Tariff.title).
At the same time, in the entity Contract, JoinColumn is explicitly specified on Tariff.
The list of options in Contract is displayed correctly.
Can this problem occur due to the list of options in Contract and Tariff entitys.
The diagram and code are attached below.

[SCHEMA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I929Q.png)

Noticed a discrepancy between entities and the schema.
Updated the entity to match the schema. (24.07.20)

Option entity code:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "option_table")
public class Option implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "option_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer optionId;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Integer price;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    private Integer cost;
        //getters,setters
```

Tariff entity code:

```
    Entity
@Table(name = "tariff_table")
public class Tariff implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tariff_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer tariffId;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private Double price;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable( name = "tariff_option",
                joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tariff_id")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "option_id")})
    private List<Option> optionList;enter code here
        //getters,setters
```

Contract entity code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract_table")
public class Contract implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "contract_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer contractId;

    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tariff_id", referencedColumnName = "tariff_id")
    private Tariff contractTariff;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable( name = "contract_option",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "contract_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "option_id")})
    private List<Option> contractOptionList;
     //getters,setters
```

Tomcat log:

```
22-Jul-2020 19:16:41.640 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
22-Jul-2020 19:16:41.858 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22-Jul-2020 19:16:58.441 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcher'
22-Jul-2020 19:17:44.898 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [ecare.domain.Tariff#1] - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
        at ecare.domain.Tariff$HibernateProxy$qthLTppY.toString(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToString(ELSupport.java:492)
        at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:524)
        at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
        at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:304)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:192)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:701)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.contract_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(contract_jsp.java:211)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.contract_jsp._jspService(contract_jsp.java:160)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
36:                         <p>Contract Info</p>
37:                         <h3>Contract id: ${contract.tariff}</h3>
38:                         <h3>Contract option list:</h3>
39:                         <h3></h3>
40: 


Stacktrace:] with root cause
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [ecare.domain.Tariff#1] - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:170)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:310)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
        at ecare.domain.Tariff$HibernateProxy$qthLTppY.toString(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToString(ELSupport.java:492)
        at org.apache.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:524)
        at org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:47)
        at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:304)
        at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:192)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:701)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.contract_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(contract_jsp.java:211)
        at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.contract_jsp._jspService(contract_jsp.java:160)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:171)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
22-Jul-2020 19:17:44.898 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [РџСЂРѕРёР·РѕС€Р»Р° РѕС€РёР±РєР° РїСЂРё РѕР±СЂР°Р±РѕС‚РєРµ [/WEB-INF/views/contract.jsp] РІ СЃС‚СЂРѕРєРµ [37]

34:                 <div class="thumbnail">
35:                     <div class="caption">
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the session could be alive until the jps calls to getTariff() as I never worked with jsp or any kind of templates with Spring. But as your relationship is LAZY, if the session is closed, hibernate won't be able to load the tariff.

In the mean time you could try to load the tariff while you get the contract, something useful are the EntityGraphs:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph

On the **example 77** the query for `getByGroupName` fetchs the attribute `members` from the `GroupInfo` entity